# adding items to columns/rows in listview using foreach

Tags: c#, listview, foreach, itemscontrol

I am into day 5 of learning c#, and am trying to figure out how to fill/re-fill a ListView control, containing 10 rows and 12 columns, using a foreach loop.  I have coded the functionality I'm after in C.

```
void listPopulate(int *listValues[], int numberOfColumns, int numberOfRows)
{
    char table[100][50];
    for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < numberOfColumns; ++columnNumber)
    {
        for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < numberOfRows; ++rowNumber)
        {
            sprintf(&table[columnNumber][rowNumber], "%d", listValues[columnNumber][rowNumber]);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have figured out so far:

```
public void listView1_Populate()
{

    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("value1");
    item1.SubItems.Add("value1a");
    item1.SubItems.Add("value1b");

    ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("value2");
    item2.SubItems.Add("value2a");
    item2.SubItems.Add("value2b");

    ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("value3");
    item3.SubItems.Add("value3a");
    item3.SubItems.Add("value3b");
    ....

    listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2, item3 });
}
```

I'm assuming that I would have to do the creation of the list items in a separate step.  So my question is: there must be a way to do this in C# with a for or foreach loop, no?

Comment: My question is: there must be a way to do this in C# with a for or foreach loop, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but here's i think what you need...

Actually it depends on your `DataSource` which you are using to fill up the `ListView`.
Something like this (I am using `Dictioanry` as a DataSource here) -

```
        // Dictinary DataSource containing data to be filled in the ListView
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> Values = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            { "val1", new List<string>(){ "val1a", "val1b" } },
            { "val2", new List<string>(){ "val2a", "val2b" } },
            { "val3", new List<string>(){ "val3a", "val3b" } }
        };

        // ListView to be filled with the Data
        ListView listView = new ListView();

        // Iterate through Dictionary and fill up the ListView
        foreach (string key in Values.Keys)
        {
            // Fill item
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(key);

            // Fill Sub Items
            List<string> list = Values[key];
            item.SubItems.AddRange(list.ToArray<string>());

            // Add to the ListView
            listView.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

I have simplified the code for your understanding, since there several ways to iterate through a `Dictionary`...

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You do this almost exactly the same as in C. Just loop through the collection...

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var column in listValues)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem("column " + i++);
    foreach (var row in column)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(row);
    }        
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

It's hard to provide a real example without seeing what your collection looks like, but for an array of arrays this will work.