# c# Add new row in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I read data from a database using sql-statements, which you can type in a textbox.
When I run the query I want to add the returned data into different columns of the listview.

My code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(textBoxQuery.Text, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                GridView view = new GridView();
                string[] head = getColumnsName(textBoxQuery.Text);//Getting the columns names
                for (int i = 0; i != reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                      view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = head[i] });//columns heading
                }
                listView.View = view;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                     for (int i = 0; i != reader.FieldCount; i++)
                     {
                        //inserting data into one row and different columns
                     }
                     Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could use this to fill the listview from a Dictionary which you could create from the reader results, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11406299/2096538

Comment: no it's not possible because I use WPF and not winforms. In WPF the subitems don't exist.

Comment: Why do you do it programatically and not in the XAML file?

Comment: When I enter a new sql statement the column headings and the number of columns is changing, so I need to do it programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the columns to generate dynamically for you in WPF you need to dynamically add column definitions with appropriate bindings each time you repopulate the list view.

Try this:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ListViewTest
{
    public class Column
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string SourceField { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GridView gridView = new GridView();
            this.myListView.View = gridView;

            List<dynamic> myItems = new List<dynamic>();
            dynamic myItem;
            IDictionary<string, object> myItemValues;

            // Populate the objects with dynamic columns
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                myItem = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

                foreach (string column in new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Something" })
                {
                    myItemValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)myItem;
                    myItemValues[column] = "My value for " + column + " - " + i;
                }

                myItems.Add(myItem);
            }

            // Assuming that all objects have same columns - using first item to determine the columns
            List<Column> columns = new List<Column>();

            myItemValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)myItems[0];

            // Key is the column, value is the value
            foreach (var pair in myItemValues)
            {
                Column column = new Column();

                column.Title = pair.Key;
                column.SourceField = pair.Key;

                columns.Add(column);
            }

            // Add the column definitions to the list view
            gridView.Columns.Clear();

            foreach (var column in columns)
            {
                var binding = new Binding(column.SourceField);

                gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Title, DisplayMemberBinding = binding });
            }

            // Add all items to the list
            foreach (dynamic item in myItems)
            {
                this.myListView.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="myListView"></ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Only thing you need to change is adding columns from the reader by using the column name from sql query. And populating the `ExpandoObject` from `fields` returned by the `reader` from your query.

This is a quick demo I written up and didn't have access to a local database to test it so I mimicked it by the for loops and the string array.